# How does the constraints GUI work in SQL Server Management Studio?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

In my TSQL table I added a constraint with the following sQL statement

```
alter table disabledqualities
add constraint uc_uIdQualCode
unique (userId, qualitycode)
```

I did it by hand because I just can't work out how the GUI is supposed to work.
You add a constraint and then you get a window where you should "define" your constraint. It's basically just a textbox. And no matter what I seem to enter, it never validates..

What am I supposed to enter in the box?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you would use **new index** not new constraint to add a unique constraint (read index)
**new constraint** is to add check constraints

in the **new index** window check unique

Comment: I should have known that a unique CONSTRAINT is not in the CONSTRAINT dialogue. Is it just me or does sql server management studio really suck?

Comment: these are semantics really, if you look under keys you will find Primary Key Constraints there....I guess you have to know where to look :-(...I doubt people would want to find a Primary Key under constraints....

Comment: Yes, you are probably right. I just seem to have a personal issue with studio. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Example, column must be between 0 and 1,

```
((0)<=[TABLE].[COLUMN] AND [TABLE].[COLUMN]<=(1))
```

When adding unique constraints, it's actually an index, like primary key, so you click on indexes/keys.